# How to display the current data and previous data entered via form in react

Tags: reactjs

Thanks for the help in advance. Currently, I am learning react. As a part of learning, I'm working on a basic expense listing app. In it, I was able to list the data entered through the form. But the problem is that when the new data is entered the previous one gets disappeared. I want to list the current as well as the previous data. Can anyone help me to resolve this.

App.js

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import ExpenseAddForm from "./ExpenseAddForm/ExpenseAddform";
import ExpenseList from "./ExpenseList/ExpenseList";
const App = () => {
  const [expensesData, setExpensesData] = useState("");
  const FormData = (datas) => {
    setExpensesData(datas);
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="new-expense">
        <ExpenseAddForm FormData={FormData} />
      </div>
      <ExpenseList listDatas={expensesData}></ExpenseList>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

ExpenseAddform.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ExpenseAddForm.css";
const ExpenseAddForm = (props) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");

  const titleHandler = (e) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
  };
  const amountHandler = (e) => {
    setAmount(e.target.value);
  };
  const dateHandler = (e) => {
    setDate(e.target.value);
  };

  const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = {
      title: title,
      amount: amount,
      date: date,
    };
    props.FormData(formData);
    setTitle("");
    setAmount("");
    setDate("");
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <div className="new-expense__controls">
        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={titleHandler} value={title} />
        </div>
        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>Amount</label>
          <input type="number" onChange={amountHandler} value={amount} />
        </div>
        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="date" onChange={dateHandler} value={date} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="new-expense__actions">
        <button type="submit">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit">Add Expense</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
export default ExpenseAddForm;
```

ExpenseList.js

```
 import React from "react";
import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem/ExpenseItem";
import ExpenseDateFilter from "./ExpenseDateFilter/ExpenseDateFilter";
import "./ExpenseList.css";

const ExpenseList = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="expenses">
      <ExpenseDateFilter />
      <ExpenseItem expenseInfos={props.listDatas} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExpenseList;
```

ExpenseItem.js

```
import React from "react";
// import ExpenseDate from "../ExpenseDate/ExpenseDate";
import "./ExpenseItem.css";

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="expense-item">
      {/* <ExpenseDate enteredDate={props.expenseInfos.date} /> */}
      <div className="expense-item__description">
        <h2>{props.expenseInfos.title}</h2>
        {/* <div className="expense-item__price">${props.expenseInfos.amount}</div> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExpenseItem;
```

ExpenseDateFilter.js

```
 import React from "react";
    const ExpenseDateFilter = () => {
      return (
        <div className="expenses-filter">
          <div className="expenses-filter__control">
            <label>Filter by year</label>
            <select>
              <option value="2022">2022</option>
              <option value="2021">2021</option>
              <option value="2020">2020</option>
              <option value="2019">2019</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default ExpenseDateFilter;
```

Comment: please add ExpenseDateFilter code or upload your code on codesandbox and comment the link

Comment: Added the ExpenseDateFilter code.Please check and comment your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is on each submit your overriding the expensesData with the new data
instead you need to do

```
const FormData = (datas) => {
setExpensesData([...expensesData,datas]);
};
```

now you have list of data next you need to handle multiple expenses data in ExpenseList.js

```
{props.listDatas.map((data,key)=>
  <ExpenseItem expenseInfos={data} />
  )}
```

and it should be done here is a link of a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-grass-g2k1fh?file=/src/App.js:467-476